# Image plane mark on Grass Valley Infinity

Tags: camera, image-sensors

I'm working on a Grass Valley Infinity and for a specific application I need to know the image plane position (ie sensor position).[image: Grass Valley Infinity]

But I can't find the image plane mark like this :
[image]

So I have two question :

1. Is someone know any informations about this on the Grass Valley Infinity ?
2. Is there always an image plane mark on a camera ? I thought it was a "norm" for professional cameras.